# How to manually limit number of post in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

here is the code which I was trying to modify to limit the number of post.

```
$loopcount = 0;
    $additional_loop = new WP_Query("paged=$paged&cat=".$k_option['gallery']['gallery_cat_final']."&posts_per_page=".$k_option['gallery']['post_count']);
```

The number of post seem to get it from $posts_per_page with the default number of post set in WordPress.

How do I change it manually?

I tried to do it like:

```
"&posts_per_page="6);
```

It won't work!

I am not good at PHP, so please guys help me!

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This post can help - http://digwp.com/2009/12/limit-posts-without-plugin/

There are two methods, one is to take a variable and loop it till your desired limit and keep incrementing it.

Here is the code snippet for the same.

```
<?php $i = 1; while (have_posts() && $i < 6) : the_post(); ?>

    <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
    <p>?php the_time(); ?></p>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
    <p><?php the_tags(); ?></p>

<?php $i++; endwhile; ?>

    <p><?php next_posts_link(); ?></p>
    <p><?php previous_posts_link(); ?></p>

<?php else : ?>

    <h1>Not Found</h1>
    <p>Silly monkey.</p>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this would help ypu :)

```
<?php
 $args = array(
'post_type' => 'post',
'posts_per_page' => 12,
'paged' => $page,
);

query_posts($args);?>
?>
```